# Posterior distribution of a random variable

Tags: distributions, bayesian, posterior

Im not understanding the following;

suppose $y \sim N (\mu,\sigma^2)$
and we have a prior $\mu \sim N (\mu_0, \sigma^2_1)$

Then we  can figure out the posterior distribution.

What i dont understand is suppose

$y=\mu+e$ where $e \sim N(0,\sigma^2_e)$
how do I know that  $y \sim N (\mu,\sigma^2)$ 
i.e. how do I know that Y is centered around $\mu$?
Won't it be centered around $\mu_0$? Because;

$E(y)=E(\mu)+E[e]=\mu_0$

Comment: In the statement $y=\mu + e$, $\mu$ is a _realization_ of a random variable and the allegation that $y \sim N (\mu,\sigma^2)$ is not quite true. $ N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the _conditional_ distribution of $y$ _given_ that another random variable (the unknown mean) took on a specific value. Thus, $E(y)$ as you write it is actually $E[y\mid \mu]$, the _conditional_ mean of $y$ given the value of $\mu$. Bayesian methods deal with finding $f_{\mu\mid y}$, the _a posteriori_ distribution of $\mu$ from the _conditional_ distribution $f_{y\mid \mu}$ and the _a priori_ distribution $f_\mu$ of the mean.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Dilip Sarwate, the key is conditioning which is often implicit in Bayesian notation. So what you really wanted was

$$ y|\mu,\sigma^2 \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) $$
and 
$$\mu|\mu_0,\sigma_1^2 \sim N(\mu_0,\sigma_1^2) $$
and thus 
$$ E[y|\mu,\sigma^2] = \mu,$$
i.e. if we knew the true value for $\mu$, then $y$ would be centered at it. And 
$$E[y|\mu_0,\sigma_1^2] = E[E[y|\mu,\sigma^2]| \mu_0,\sigma_1^2] = E[\mu|\mu_0,\sigma_1^2] = \mu_0$$
i.e. our prior guess about where the data y will be is centered around $\mu_0$.